# [SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm implementing ML project on intellij using airflow and docker and I'm facing the below issue.

```
project_p-webserver-1  | [2023-08-11 15:20:49,515] {cli_action_loggers.py:105} WARNING - Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: log
project_p-webserver-1  | [SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
```

below is my docker-compose file:

```
    version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"

  webserver:
    build: ./dockerfiles
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE=true
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME=airflow
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD=airflow
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins

    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

my docker-file :

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:2.1.0
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0
COPY requirement.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
```

I'm getting the sql error with airflow 404 error initially I was facing issue with the flask user not avaialble error then fixed that now I'm getting this error can any please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a connection to your DB. Try adding parameter `AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` to `environment` section:

```yaml
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE=true
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME=airflow
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD=airflow
      - AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
```

You can see the docker-compose recommended by Airflow developers here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml

I found a link in the instruction:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html